# i hav an error in following code: invalid AES key length 9 bytes and java.lang.NullPointerException exception in main

Tags: java, eclipse, aes

Plz do tell me from where to study these encryptions, hashing; all in eclipse java

i hav an error in following code: invalid AES key length 9 bytes and java.lang.NullPointerException exception in main.

There is also an exception of java.security.InvalidKeyException.
i have made my code in eclipse kepler 64 bit.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.*;

public class aes {
    final static String Plaintext="difficult";
    final static String pswd="secretkey";
    public static Key setkey(String mykey)
    {
        Key skey=null;
        try
        {
             skey=new SecretKeySpec(mykey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return skey;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String plaintxt)
    {
        String encryptedtxt=null;
        try
        {
            Key skey=aes.setkey(pswd);
            Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
            byte[] P=plaintxt.getBytes("UTF-8");
            encryptedtxt=new String(c.doFinal(P));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedtxt;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedtxt)
    {
        try{
            Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            Key skey=aes.setkey(pswd);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
            String decryptedtxt=new String(c.doFinal(encryptedtxt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            return decryptedtxt;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Plain text    :"+Plaintext);
        String encryptedtxt=aes.encrypt(Plaintext.trim());
        System.out.println("encrypted text:"+encryptedtxt);
        String decryptedtxt=aes.decrypt(encryptedtxt.trim());
        System.out.println("decrypted text:"+decryptedtxt);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything if an exception is thrown and the "try" is exited early...

Comment: Other notes: a key should not just contain characters, you are using a default mode of operation for your AES cipher, and that mode is ECB mode, which is insecure. You can remove the `EncodingException` by using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` (possibly using a static import). You can also use a multi-catch or just a `catch (GeneralSecurityException e)` to do way with many exceptions, although `IllegalBlockSizeException` and `BadPaddingException` are indicating wrong input and *should* be handled separately.

Comment: Oh, and as encryption returns a byte array that is indistinguishable from random, using `new String` will fail. Your key should be 128, 192 or 256 bits.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers, or indicate why they don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested change (to pacify the compiler):

```
public static String encrypt(String plaintxt)            //line 24
    {
        String encryptedtxt = null;
        try
        {
            Key skey=aes.setkey(pswd);
            Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
            byte[] P=plaintxt.getBytes("UTF-8");
            encryptedtxt=new String(c.doFinal(P));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedtxt;
    }
```

Comment: Note: if this solution is taken it might be necessary to null check the return from this method depending on it's use.

Comment: Yup.  All things being equal, I'd lose the try/catch block, and let the caller handle the exception.  But assuming the OP wants a try/catch, and doesn't want to do anything except print the traceback to stdout ... then yes, the caller should check for "null".

Comment: I'm not so much in favor of this solution; it changes the runtime code, introduces the "billion dollar mistake" (null pointers), keeps on running on an important exception and does not remove the cause.

Comment: i edited my code but there is one error coming which is skey cannot b resolved to a variable.
        public static Key setkey(String mykey)
 {
  try
  {
   SecretKeySpec skey=new SecretKeySpec(mykey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return skey;
 }

Comment: The error is occuring because you declare skey *inside* the try/catch block, but you're returning it *outside*.  Your `return skey` is out of scope.  SOLUTION: Declare `Key skey = null;` just *before* the "try" statement.

Comment: i tried using this before but it gave an error of invalid aes key length 9 bytes and an exception in main: java.lang.NullPointerexception

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your exception handling. If an exception takes place, you print out the value and continue. But if you continue, you do not return a `String`.

Many IDE's automatically fill in `.e.printStackTrace()` which is a rather dangerous practice and mucks with the runtime execution, as execution continues - if it compiles at all.

Most of the time, I replace this behavior with:

```
// TODO handle exception correctly
throw new IllegalStateException("Exception not yet handled", e);
```

which throws a runtime exception which you do not have to handle.

Comment: Extra points if you make `TODO` a task tag, as you can do in Eclipse. `throw AssertError("Handle exception")` could also work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot `, e`, which includes the original exception as the cause.

Comment: In Eclipse, Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code style -> Code templates -> Catch block body looks like you can fix it to make Eclipse fill in your preferred behavior automatically.  I haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Stop swallowing the exceptions or throw a custom one at the end of the method.